# Mongodb $sum with Subarray list item values

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

**I am trying to calculate total number of products in my order which was actually in sub-array.**

**Facing trouble with $sum while trying to calculate.**

My Attempt

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
{$match:{'order_no':'GHT19'}},
{$unwind:"$products_list"}
])
```

My Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57838a3a3628f76b52511ffe"),
    "order_no" : "GHT19",
    "origin_port" : "Vizag Port",
    "destination_port" : "Hankou Port"
    "products_list" : {
        "box_no" : "1",
        "product_name" : "Mobile",
        "qty" : "5"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57838a3a3628f76b52511ffe"),
    "order_no" : "GHT19",
    "origin_port" : "Vizag Port",
    "destination_port" : "Hankou Port"
    "products_list" : {
        "box_no" : "2",
        "product_name" : "Television",
        "qty" : "2"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57838a3a3628f76b52511ffe"),
    "order_no" : "GHT19",
    "origin_port" : "Vizag Port",
    "destination_port" : "Hankou Port",
    "products_list" : {
        "box_no" : "3",
        "product_name" : "Radio",
        "qty" : "2"
    }

}
```

While trying to do SUM like below

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
{$match:{'order_no':'GHT19'}},
{$unwind:"$products_list"},
{$group: {
    _id: '$products_list.box_no', 
    "total_products": {$sum: "$products_list.qty" }
  }
}
])
```

I am getting ZERO result. Please see the below result.

```
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "total_products" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : "3",
    "total_products" : 0
}


{
    "_id" : "1",
    "total_products" : 0
}
```

Please find the best solution for my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your agreggation is correct, the problem is that qty field is a String. Try changing it to "qty":3. That should work

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. I have even changed "_id" : 1 in the $group. Finally, I got result :)

Answer (score 0):

You can compute `$sum` only with numeric value : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

You can convert all your `products_list.qty` to numeric with :

```
db.device.find().forEach(function(data) {

    data.products_list.forEach(function(data2) {

        db.device.update({
            "_id": data._id,
            "products_list.box_no": data2.box_no
        }, {
            "$set": {
                "products_list.$.qty": parseInt(data2.qty)
            }
        });

    });
})
```

And then execute your aggregation